How do i add "Sign in with google" with passport.js but keep my normal sign up api's that uses jwt authentication?
I am building my final year project where I want to integrate google auth with traditional Sign up and Login auth, but the problem is that whenever i watch a passport.js tutorial or docs they start it from the scratch and just use passport.js but I want to keep my jwt authentication alive and just add on sign in with google.
After going through a lot of docs I came up with that schema If any one tell me if I am going in the right direction and what docs or tutorial should I follow next.
Schema:
    enum AuthProvider {
      LOCAL
      OAUTH
    }

    model User {
      id String @id @default(uuid()) 
      name String
      email String @unique
      password String?
      avatar String?
      resume String?
      skills Json?
      authProvider AuthProvider @default(LOCAL)
      oAuthId String? @unique 
      passwordResetToken String? 
      passwordResetExpiry DateTime?
      emailVerificationToken String?
      emailVerificationExpiry DateTime? 
      savedJobs Job[] @relation("UserSavedJobs")
      createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    }


After also reading through the passport.js docs a bit, I suggest you try to accomplish your goals with the JWT strategy by passport: https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/
and the Google strategy by passport: https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/
If you don't want to use passport at all, this post goes into detail on how to do it yourself without a library by Google: https://permify.co/post/oauth-20-implementation-nodejs-expressjs/
Google does also provide a library to make things a bit easier: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest
